# SignalR MVC 5 Websocket no valid Credentials

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, controller, signalr, owin

i try to use SignalR in MVC Application. It works well but i get the following Error in the Chrome console

```
 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:18245/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=bNDGLnbSQThqY%2FSjo1bt
8%2FL45Xs22BDs2VcY8O7HIkJdDaUJ4ftIc54av%2BELjr27ekHUiTYWgFMfG6o7RaZwhf
fpXavzWQ1jvkaxGm5rI%2BWtK7j0g1eQC2aOYP366WmRQLXCiYJfsm4EbwX6T8n2Aw
%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22importerhub%
22%7D%5D&tid=9' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available
```

The funny thing is that the jquery method i call from the Controller over the Hub works fine.

jQuery:

```
 $(function () {
            // Initialize the connection to the server
            var importerHub = $.connection.importerHub;

            // Preparing a client side function
            // called sendMessage that will be called from the server side
            importerHub.client.sendMessage = function (message) {
                showOrUpdateSuccessMessage(message);
            };
            $.connection.hub.start();
        });
```

Controller:

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ImporterHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.All.sendMessage("All operations complete");
```

I use .Net v4.5.1, SignalR v2.1.2.0 and IIS 8.5 with Windows Authentication.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It looks like you are running into a Chrome issue. The problem is that Chrome doesn't properly handle Windows Authentication for WebSockets.

Below is the initial issue submitted a couple years ago reporting that Chrome did not support any form of HTTP authentication:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123862

That issue has been resolved for Basic and Digest authentication, but not for Windows (NTLM/Negotiate) authentication. There was an issue created less than a month ago to track progress on Chrome support for Windows authentication with WebSockets:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423609

Apparently, the issue with Windows authentication is partially fixed in the Chrome dev channel, but only if the client has already authenticated with the server prior to establishing a WebSocket.

The reason you can still call `sendMessage` from your Controller is because SignalR automatically falls back to using a transport other than WebSockets (i.e. server-sent events or long-polling), when the WebSocket connection fails. Chrome will properly handle Windows authentication with SignalR's other transports.

I suggest not changing anything. It looks like Chrome will eventually support Windows authentication for WebSockets.

The only real problem, other than the error in your chrome console, is that it might take slightly longer to establish a SignalR connection in Chrome. If that's a big issue, you can always [specify what transports the client should attempt using](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#transport). So on Chrome, you could only try `serverSentEvents` and `longPolling`, but then when Chrome *does* fix the issue, you won't be using the best possible transport until you change your code.

Comment: Thank you, the error disapear with transport options `serverSentEvents` and `longPolling`.

Comment: Simply used Microsoft Edge (new Internet Explorer) and worked

Comment: @FindOut_Quran Yes, this is a issue in Chrome. It should work correctly in the other browsers. However, we don't always have the luxury of controlling what browser other people use to view it with.

Comment: Also note that this might cause Chrome to "forget" your credentials and ask your login info when it tries to reconnect after.

Comment: Is there not a work around for this issue still? Looks like this chrome bug has been around for since 10/2014

Answer (score 0):

The bug seems to be alive, but it looks like they work on it.
You can solve the problem by using `https`/`wss`.

Read [codeMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4009972/codemonkey)s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49637422/3131852) at [*SignalR not working with Windows-integrated authentication*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612867/signalr-not-working-with-windows-integrated-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by switching to the Dev Channel of Chrome : Download from [here](https://www.chromium.org/chrome-release-channels).
Once Installed I needed to enable a dev flag in chrome://flags/.
Search for Enable WebSocket connection reuse for authentication and enable the feature.
You need to be on version 69 or greater

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it and for me this had nothing to do with Chrome. I am using chrome and it's working with real-time data. My error was spring security

```
.antMatchers("/ws/myapp", "/http/myaap", "/topic/**", "/app/**" ).permitAll()
```

[WebSocket Handshake - Unexpected response code 200 - AngularJs and Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845452/websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-200-angularjs-and-spring-boot/56910091#56910091)

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts of the linked question in your post, just in case the link dies.