# SignalR not working with Windows-integrated authentication

Tags: asp.net, websocket, signalr, windows-authentication, ntlm

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app (.NET 4.5) and SIgnalR works fine with forms-based authentication (hosted via IIS/IIS Express)

As soon as I change the app to windows-integrated authentication (`<authentication mode="Windows"/>` in "web.config") it stops working.

> *jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js:9* WebSocket connection to `ws://localhost:51030/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&blhablahblah` failed: **Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403**

After adding the `[Authorize]` attribute to my hub, the error changes to

> WebSocket connection to `ws://localhost:51030/signalr/connect?transport=webSocketsblahblah` failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available

Other parts of the app are working just fine, windows-auth is enabled on the server and works, etc. etc.

**How do I solve this?**

And if it is unsolvable for some reason (it could be Chrome not supporting windows auth on websocket connections or something else) - **why doesn't it fall back to non-websocket protocol?** and how do I force the fallback?

UPDATE: I created a github issue https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3953. The problem is not that I can't connect. The problem is that I cannot handle the error to fall back to another transport. Neither `.fail()` not `.error()` are being invoked. Try-catch doesn't help either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update from 2020: looks like Chrome now supports NTLM on WS-connections, not an issue any more

---

*...10 hours later after asking the question...*

**Partially solved** (answering my own question)

After playing with it I can confirm, that adding the `[Authorize]` attribute to my hub (or alternatively, adding `GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();` to your "Startup.cs") actually does help. **It does fall back now** to an alternative transport, even though the error is still thrown into the browser's console.

You can also specify **which** transport it falls back to, by calling:

```
$.connection.hub.start( { transport: ['webSockets', 'longPolling'] });
```

in case you don't like the default priority (I guess, "hidden iframe" is the default second option).

**The reason**

The error is caused by Chrome, it does not support NTLM on websocket connections. Funny enough, IE, MS Edge and Firefox do support it ("Chrome is the new IE" huh).

There's an open issue in Chromium bugtracker for this here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423609 if anyone wants to add any input to Chromium devs.

Comment: I've added [Authorize] to my hub, and called GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication(); in Startup.cs but i still couldnt get it to work. Then i added the transport types in JS and still can't get it work. Anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I too was experiencing this error, but only when developing locally using `http`; I think Chrome doesn't like unsecured `ws://` connections.  Once I deployed to server with secure `https` connection, the WebSocket connection was upgraded to `wss://`, and Chrome stopped complaining, worked fine with WebSockets--didn't have to fall back to other transport.

tl:dr; Make sure to use `https` for your site.