# How to enable Windows Authentication in AspNetCore SignalR Alpha

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

How do I configure SignalR to Authenticate/Authorize to a server that is must be protected by Windows Authentication.  There appears to be no way to make the JavaScript Client send Credentials with the request.

Comment: This should be handled by the browser.

Comment: @Pawel  Thank you for your reply.  Upon further examination, it appears that you are correct in Edge and FireFox; however, Chrome and Opera report:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:54601/chat?id=a39248a4-c068-4397-badc-e8a98316cffd' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available
Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Undefined]

Comment: As another quirk, Edge requires a PIV card login, while FireFox still asks for a UserName/Password...  Perhaps Webkit is having trouble with the PIV card?

Comment: Take a look at this thread https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/986 - it shows possible workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows authentication should be handled by the browser and you should not have to do anything special. The problem is that Chrome does not seem to handle Windows Authentication correctly. There is a [thread on github](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/986) that contains more details.

Also, [SignalR MVC 5 Websocket no valid Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863242/signalr-mvc-5-websocket-no-valid-credentials) seems still to apply as the issue is browser related (i.e. external to SignalR).